# shiny how apply different regression model

Tags: r, shiny, regression

I would like to chose one of regression models from a selection of different kind of models and, then, apply it to a subset. But I've difficult to understand how I can paste the function in server.R
Here there is a part of code in ui.R

```
h3("Model Prediction"),
selectInput("regression", "Select  Model:",
list("y~x", 
"y~x^2")
```

In server.R I've written this code

```
dati<- as.data.frame( read.csv(file='file.csv', header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=","))
mydata <- reactive({
    (pdata=subset(dati,index==input$proj))
})

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    #Simple plot
    output$testPlot = renderPlot({
        pdata=subset(dati,index==input$proj)
        plot(pdata$gg, pdata$y )
    })
    ###my data
    mydata <- reactive({
        (pdata=subset(dati,index==input$proj))
    })

    runRegression <- reactive({
        lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"))),data=dat)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `sprintf` for it 
like

```
selectInput("regression", "Select  Model:",
list("y~x"="%s", 
        "y~x^2"="%s^2"))


as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(sprintf(fmt = input$regression,input$independent),collapse="+")))
```